# ANDROID Adaptor inflating dynamic layout from its string name

Tags: android, adapter, android-cardview, layout-inflater

I have on stacked card view. So each card is set tasks. For that each card may have different layouts.I want know how to inflate the different layout .

To do that i created on string array to hold my all layout name.

```
private ArrayList<String> LayOutData;
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) { 
   LayOutData.add("card_"+(x + 1));
}
```

This `LayOutData` i am passing to my adaptor like

```
mAdapter = new SwipeStackAdapter(mData,LayOutData);
```

my layout name are like

```
card_1.xml
card_2.xml
card_3.xml
card_4.xml
```

This is the static way setting the layout for the view.

```
convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_1, parent, false);
```

But how can i inflate the names that i have created the already with the card index.
My try for this is below.

```
switch (position){
                case 0:
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_1, parent, false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_2, parent, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_3, parent, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_3, parent, false);
                    break;
                default:
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_1, parent, false);
                    break;
            }
```

I know this is not good way to code can you please suggest some way to this.

Comment: if your card_view layout is common make single and inflate the text in the layout that is the good approach

Comment: @DarpanS.Raut my card view is diffrent ie interms of the each card contains diffrent diffrent task

Comment: so can you use fragment? and the call the desired fragment on logic

Comment: unfortunately android inflater does not work directly with layout names, it works only with generated ids, so you would still need to use them, however you can declare your mapping elsewhere and then just shorten UI code a la `getLayoutInflater().inflate(map.get(position), parent, false);`

Comment: @OlegBogdanov is this correct way of using `convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(Integer.parseInt(LayOutData.get(position)), parent, false);`

Comment: I'm afraid its not, parseint would expect there to be really int but you have a file name that can't be parsed into an int. You would need to fill your LayOutData with ids, like `R.layout.card_1, R.layout.card_2, ...`

Comment: ill try to fill the `LayOutData with ids, like R.layout.card_1, R.layout.card_2`

Comment: @PranavMS could you check my answer? It actually does what you need

Comment: yeah iam try that only.

Comment: @OrestSavchak now getting error that ` cannot resolve method getResources()` i tried like this  `int id=getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(LName, "layout", getPackageName()); convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, parent, false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int id = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cardName, "layout", packageName);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, parent, false);
```

Comment: now getting error that ` cannot resolve method getResources()` i tried like this int id=getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(LName, "layout", getPackageName()); convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, parent, false);

Comment: Do you have a Context reference in your adapter? Where did you get the LayoutInflater?

Comment: i have solved that using `getApplicationContext()`  thanks it is working fine now.

Comment: can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740574/android-a-layout-contains-multiple-multiselectionspinner